# Eclipse plugin for Fluent API methods

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, fluent, fluent-interface

I'm looking for an eclipse plugin that can generate fluent API methods in my beans.

For instance, given this bean:

```
public class MyBean {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    //Setters and getters
}
```

Is there any eclipse plugin that generates these methods for me?

```
public class MyBean {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    public MyBean withName(String name) {
        setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public MyBean withAge(int age) {
        setAge(age);
        return this;
    }

    //Setters and getters
}
```

I've found a [google plugin](https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/) that generates `Builder` objects, but I prefer fluent API inside each Bean class.

Answer (score 4):

While can't find anything, you can do like me.

Generate the setters, then "Find" (checking "regular expressions") for:

`\tpublic void set(.+)\((.+)\) \{\R\t\tthis\.(.+) = (.+);\R\t\}`

and replace with:

`\tpublic [PUT_TYPE_HERE] with$1\($2\) \{\R\t\tthis\.$3 = $4;\R\t\treturn this;\R\t\}`

Probably there's a simpler expression, but this works ;)

**[UPDATE] @ 07-MAR-2018**

I'm now using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org) which generates `getters`, `setters` and `builders` throught simple annotations. (`@Getter`, `@Setter` and `@Builder` respectively)

It can generate `with` methods using the `@Wither` annotation too, but unfortunately its an experimental feature so it should be avoided.